Pulseaudio custom volume control
I have a PC running OpenSuSE 15.5 with Pulseaudio 15. I am routing my audio via HDMI to my AV receiver, which obviously has volume control built in. If I now change my volume via software (eg. via media keys), this changes the volume of the audio sent to the receiver, not the receiver volume. However, my receiver has an API which I could use to set, among other things, the volume. My question now is: Is it somehow possible to tell PA to do this, eg. by creating some virtual device (?) that calls a script for getting and changing the current volume? Ideally I'd have some interface where PA requests to change the volume and I do API calls and I can, on external changes (eg. I adjust the volume directly on the receiver), notify PA of the change.
